# QueryString Out of Encoded URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an encoded URL.

```
http%3a%2f%myurl.test.me%2fSometjing%2fProduct%2fSearch%3fq=Tomato
```

I am trying to get query string out of the url which is "Tomato". I am using the following code but it returns null.

```
 var parsedQuery = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString((url));
            Console.Write(parsedQuery["q"]); // null
```

Comment: Of course it returns null - the URL is completely encoded. You need to decode it first. You should also fix the `http://` portion: `http%3a%2f%2fmyurl.test.me%2fSometjing%2fProduct%2fSearch%3fq=Tomato`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a few steps. You need to decode the URL, then pull out the query string, and then parse the query string:

```
string decoded = 
    HttpUtility.UrlDecode("http%3a%2f%2fmyurl.test.me%2fSometjing%2fProduct%2fSearch%3fq=Tomato");

var uri = new Uri(decoded);
var parsedQuery = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

Console.WriteLine (parsedQuery["q"]); // Tomato
```

Also, your encoded URL is a little malformed. The one in your post decoded looks like this:

> http:/%myurl.test.me/Sometjing/Product/Search?q=Tomato

I think you just missed a `2f` after the `%` right before `myurl.test`:

> http%3a%2f%2fmyurl.test.me%2fSometjing%2fProduct%2fSearch%3fq=Tomato

Answer (score 0):

The URL needs to decoded first before you can use the `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`.

Fair warning though mentioned directly from MSDN.

> The ParseQueryString method uses query strings that might contain user input, which is a potential security threat. By default, ASP.NET Web pages validate that user input does not include script or HTML elements. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150047(v=vs.110).aspx).